# Stopping execution of an invoked task

Tags: ruby, thor

Using Thor, I have one task which invokes another:

```
desc "prepare", "Update with the latest coursegen code and templates."
def prepare
  invoke check
  tplt = CourseGen::Templates.new
  tplt.generate_all
end
```

The idea is that if the 'check' task fails, that the prepare task doesn't run. How do I cause the error detected by check to cause the prepare task to stop? I am reporting the error in check with a call to error, and that does not do the trick:

```
desc "check", "verify that this is a valid cg directory"
def check
  CourseGen::Templates.new.valid_cg_directory? ? 
    say("Valid cg directory") :
    error("Invalid cg directory")
end
```

Comment: why do you make it an extra task instead of doing it inline or calling it as a method?

Comment: Just to share the code. I need it as a stand alone task as well as call it. But what about the right way to stop execution?